# Android : Stop Activity(s) after starting Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I have the following flow in my code:

```
 Activity1 : startActivity(Activity2) --->
             Activity2: startActivity(Activity3) --->
                        Activity3: startService(MyService) --->
                                   MyService: startActivity(Activity4)
```

Each Activity above shows a single view and represents a step in a 4-step setup. The final Activity - `Activity 4` - is started after some setup work is done inside `MyService`, which basically tells the user,

`"The service has started, you can close the application by pressing Back or Home button"`

When the user presses Back or Home, I want to destroy `Activities 1-4` , and only have  `MyService` running. Also, after stopping the Application as above, when the user navigates back to the Application via the menu and starts it, I'll be checking if `MyService` is already running. If it is already running, I don't want to show `Activities 1-3`, I want to show another `Control Panel View` (Another Activity), which says,

`"Dude, the service is already running, do you want to Stop or Restart it?"`

This view will have a Stop and Restart button, to do the appropriate tasks.

**My Questions:**

1. How do I stop Activities 1-4 from inside Activity 4 when Back or Home is pressed,safely? My thought was to add a `static stopActivity()` method to each Activity, and calling `Activity[1-3].stopActivity()` from `onBackPressed()` or `onPause()` of **Activity4**. Then inside each `stopActivity()`, I'll call `finish()`, thus ending each Activity. But is it safe and efficient to do it this way?
2. The flow I have illustrated above, is it the optimal way of doing things, or is there a cleaner way? I have `BroadcastReceivers` registered in these Activities, so I need to perform clean exits for each Activity, without leaked receivers, or worse, crashing the App  or affect the User's phone due to unclean exit strategies.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: There are several possible ways to implement this. To give you better answer, please indicate if the user can use the "BACK" key to go from `Activity3` -> `Activity2` -> `Activity1`. Also, what should happen if the user is in `Activity3`, `Activity2` or `Activity1` and presses the HOME key. When he returns to the app should he start at the beginning (`Activity1`) again? or should he return to the activity that he left.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to stop activities, Android will do it for you. Start your activities using intents with the flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY) so they won't appear when the user presses back. Those activities will be stopped as soon as the user leaves them.
2. In the `onStop` method of each of your activities, write any code you want to deallocate memory if there is something you want to deallocate manually, although that wouldn't be necessary because Android will deallocate it for yourself when the device is short on memory. In those `onStop` methods unregister any `BroadcastReceiver`previously registered.